# Adding a CUSTOM network to Gnosis Safe

Tags: gnosis-safe

I want to add custom RPC settings so that I can view my PulseChain Testnet sacrifice balances, but there is no option to add a custom network. I went to the live chat and they said I would have the ask the dev's about it. I know that it is possible and need some help on how I can add a custom network.

Comment: GnosisSafe is limited to a few networks, You can deploy your own, or use a different multisig like https://safe.fantom.network/ for Fantom !

Answer (score 0):

Did you try safe-infrastructure repo from safe-global?
https://github.com/safe-global/safe-infrastructure

Answer (score 0):

The initial steps are:

1. Write an issue to add the custom network at https://github.com/safe-global/safe-singleton-factory/issues

   - The purpose of the first step is to employ a deterministic deployment proxy which allows the contracts' addresses to be predetermined
2. Deploy the Safe contracts on a custom network using https://github.com/safe-global/safe-contracts repository
3. Add the newly supported network to the safe-deployments repository located at https://github.com/safe-global/safe-deployments

   - This is because the Gnosis Safe SDK relies on an [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@gnosis.pm/safe-deployments) associated with this repository