# SafeProxy was not deployed correctly

Tags: gnosis-safe

we have the complete setup running locally and have now tried to deploy a new safe on our chain via the web UI. After creating a new Safe the process fails with: **SafeProxy was not deployed correctly.**

[image: SafeProxy was not deployed correctly in WebUI.]

This is because the **ProxyCreation** event cant be parsed in
*web-core/node_modules/@safe-global/safe-ethers-lib/dist/src/contracts/GnosisSafeProxyFactory/GnosisSafeProxyFactoryEthersContract.js:32*

The **Transaction Service** is recognizing the new safe, but says **Confirmed = false**.
[image: Unconfirmed Safes in transaction service.]

When trying to **import** the created **ProxySafe** (which we tried to create via the web ui) following error appears: **422 Unprocessable Entity**
[image: Import fails.]

Additional info:

- We could omit the errors above when deploying to Fuji C-Chain (but we couldn't finish there because the block indexer didnt find the new safe yet)
- The bytecode of our deployed contract is correct (same like on other chains)

**Do you have any idea how to successfully create a safe via the web UI?**

Answer (score 0):

Did you deploy Safe contracts on your custom chain using Gnosis’s pre-signed transaction?

I was unable to find your Shimmer chain (with a chain id of 1076) merged in the safe-global/safe-singleton-factory or safe-global/safe-deployments repositories.

If you haven’t done this yet, you can refer to this resource for guidance: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/146803/113925.

Answer (score -1):

Does the singleton factory need to be pre-signed? There must be a way to use it on a custom chain without having a pre-signed transaction. We've made our own deployment of the factory in the case in which we've got the error.

Can we be sure that the error "Unprocessable Entity" comes from a missing signature?

In either case, I've now opened an issue to add shimmer to the singleton factory repository.